# Same month two different SUMS

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I'm trying to get different Sums for same month on same Year, just to get sums by different types. Tried using this code:

```
SELECT a.invoice_type, year( a.date ) AS Year, 
       date_format( a.date, '%M' ) AS `month` , 
       Sum( x.amount * x.price ) AS sum FROM records x 
JOIN paper_invoice a ON x.invoice_id = a.invoice_id 
WHERE year( a.date ) = '2012' 
GROUP BY a.invoice_type, Year( a.date ) , Month( a.date ) LIMIT 0 , 30
```

but it gives results in different rows:

http://www.part.lt/img/1505f0f13172922150febede85ddbf0925.png

But I need it to look like:

```
Year | Month   | SUM_GRYNAIS      | SUM_PAVEDIMU
2012 | January | 7597.14997705445 | 58740.2800849304
```

and ETC.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Year, Month,
MAX(CASE WHEN invoice_type = 'GRYNAIS' THEN sum END) As Sum_GRYNAIS
MAX(CASE WHEN invoice_type = 'PAVEDIMU' THEN sum END) As SUM_PAVEDIMU
FROM
(
SELECT a.invoice_type, year( a.date ) AS Year, 
date_format( a.date, '%M' ) AS `month` , Sum( x.amount * x.price ) AS sum 
FROM records x JOIN paper_invoice a ON x.invoice_id = a.invoice_id 
WHERE year( a.date ) = '2012' GROUP BY a.invoice_type, Year( a.date ) , 
Month( a.date ) LIMIT 0 , 30     

)
GROUP BY Year, Month
```

Answer (score 0):

Because each month has a different value. Try Group By on just the field year.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically looking for PIVOT. MySql doesn't have a PIVOT function but you can still accomplish this. Here is an example of a PIVOT in MySql:

http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78